# Hardware without drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, compatibility

Windows 7 rocks! I've a lot of friends that moved from Windows XP right to Windows Seven. 
In general all hardware works fine, but I find that some webcams didn't worked and some scanners too.

Searching in the web, I discovered that the manufacturer didn't released and will not release an driver for Windows 7 (and **Windows 7 x64**)...

There are some workaround to that problem? I thougth about edit some .inf files; or to try install in compatibility mode; or find some generic driver; or using that Virtual XP...

My question is, some that my ideas can work? There are some another solution? Or my friends will need "send to trash" that old hardware?

Thank you!

Comment: What hardware is this?

Comment: By example, the scanner is Canon N1220u. I will get some webcam models and I will post here...

Answer (score 3):

I might get shot for this but: just use Vista drivers.

Don't ever install drivers in compatibility or through a virtual machine as they won't operate the right way.